# Set specific fixed range JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im using JFreechart and i want to set a fixed range from 54 to 114 with tick units of 10, so i want to show in my range axis the values {43,64,74,...,114}. The thing is that i'm already using:

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
rangeAxis.setRangeWithMargins(54, 114);
```

The problem is that JFreeChart shows me a range with {60,70,80,90,100,110} and that's not what i want and it doesn't show me the bounds. Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NumberAxis](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html) in JFreeChart always rounds to integer multiples of the tick size, and there isn't a way to change that via API calls.  But you should be able to do it by subclassing NumberAxis and overriding the method [calculateLowestVisibleTickValue()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#calculateLowestVisibleTickValue%28%29) to return the lower bound on the axis (54 in your example).  I didn't test this, so let me know if it doesn't work (I'm fairly sure it will though).

Comment: Your help was very useful. First override NumberAxis class using the one in this page http://www.opengion.org/javadocV6/src-html/org/opengion/hayabusa/io/HybsNumberAxis.html and then i called the method setTickLabelInsets this way:

    rangeAxis.setTickLabelInsets(new RectangleInsets(30,10,10,10));

Now i have my chart with {54,64,74,...,114} as i wanted!